# Can you tell if a corpse was male or female by only examining its skull?

Tags: human-anatomy, anatomy, sex

There are articles that says women have more rounded corner faces than men, than women noses are usually shorter, etc.

But are those (and other features) tendencies or deterministic features that makes you really able to tell if a corpse was male or female, by only examining its skull?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to textbook of forensic medicine and toxicology by Ks Narayan reddy:

Qualitative differences are:

1. Male mandible has everted ramus, but female have inverted ramus.
2. Males have chin U shaped, but it's rounded in females

Quantitative differences:

1. Suparaorbital ridges are prominent in males but often absent in females.
2. Mastoid process is wider, longer and blunt in males but is narrow and pointed in females.

And there are many more differences, see the pics below:

[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

Gautam Biswas says you can be 92% sure only via skull. [image]

Comment: Please give a reference for this table ("Gautam Biswas" is not sufficient)